# PySNMP Instrumentation Controller with asyncio

Tags: async-await, python-asyncio, pysnmp

I need to write simple SNMP responder where part of the job is to call some external script through `asyncio.subprocess` module. Now I am experimenting with `pysnmp` but following slightly modified code from examples doesn't work:

```
import asyncio                                                                                                                                     

from pysnmp.entity import engine, config                                                                                                           
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import cmdrsp, context                                                                                                  
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncio.dgram import udp                                                                                                       
from pysnmp.smi import instrum                                                                                                                     
from pysnmp.proto.api import v2c                                                                                                                   

snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()                                                                                                                   

config.addTransport(                                                                                                                               
    snmpEngine,                                                                                                                                    
    udp.domainName,                                                                                                                                
    udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', 161))                                                                                            
)                                                                                                                                                  

# config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'my-area', 'public')                                                                                              
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'public', 'public', contextName='my-context')                                                                       
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'private', 'private', contextName='my-context')                                                                     

# Allow full MIB access for each user at VACM                                                                                                      
config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 2, "public", 'noAuthNoPriv', (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1))                                                
config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 2, "private", 'noAuthNoPriv', (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1))                                               

# Create an SNMP context                                                                                                                           
snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(snmpEngine)                                                                                                      

# Very basic Management Instrumentation Controller without                                                                                         
# any Managed Objects attached. It supports only GET's and                                                                                         
# always echos request var-binds in response.                                                                                                      
class EchoMibInstrumController(instrum.AbstractMibInstrumController):                                                                              
    @asyncio.coroutine                                                                                                                             
    def readVars(self, varBinds, acInfo=(None, None)):                                                                                             
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)                                                                                                                
        return [(ov[0], v2c.OctetString('You queried OID %s' % ov[0])) for ov in varBinds]                                                         

# Create a custom Management Instrumentation Controller and register at                                                                            
# SNMP Context under ContextName 'my-context'                                                                                                      
snmpContext.registerContextName(                                                                                                                   
    v2c.OctetString('my-context'),  # Context Name                                                                                                 
    EchoMibInstrumController()  # Management Instrumentation                                                                                       
)                                                                                                                                                  

# Register GET&SET Applications at the SNMP engine for a custom SNMP context                                                                       
cmdrsp.GetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)                                                                                                
cmdrsp.SetCommandResponder(snmpEngine, snmpContext)                                                                                                

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()                                                                                                                    
loop.run_forever()
```

When try to make a query with following command `snmpget -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0` script fails with the following traceback.

```
Exception in callback AbstractTransportDispatcher._cbFun(<pysnmp.carri...x7f4c7540d518>, ('127.0.0.1', 44209), b'0)\x02\x01\...1\x00\x05\x00') 
handle: <Handle AbstractTransportDispatcher._cbFun(<pysnmp.carri...x7f4c7540d518>, ('127.0.0.1', 44209), b'0)\x02\x01\...1\x00\x05\x00')>      
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                             
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py", line 120, in _run                                                                               
    self._callback(*self._args)                                                                                                                
  File "/opt/profiset2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/carrier/base.py", line 70, in _cbFun                                                 
    self, transportDomain, transportAddress, incomingMessage                                                                                   
  File "/opt/profiset2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/engine.py", line 154, in __receiveMessageCbFun                                
    self, transportDomain, transportAddress, wholeMsg                                                                                          
  File "/opt/profiset2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/proto/rfc3412.py", line 421, in receiveMessage                                       
    PDU, maxSizeResponseScopedPDU, stateReference)                                                                                             
  File "/opt/profiset2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/cmdrsp.py", line 140, in processPdu                                   
    (self.__verifyAccess, snmpEngine))                                                                                                         
  File "/opt/profiset2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/cmdrsp.py", line 247, in handleMgmtOperation                          
    mgmtFun(v2c.apiPDU.getVarBinds(PDU), (acFun, acCtx)))                                                                                      
  File "/opt/profiset2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/cmdrsp.py", line 46, in sendVarBinds                                  
    v2c.apiPDU.setVarBinds(PDU, varBinds)                                                                                                      
  File "/opt/profiset2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/proto/api/v1.py", line 135, in setVarBinds                                           
    varBindList.getComponentByPosition(idx), varBind                                                                                           
  File "/opt/profiset2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysnmp/proto/api/v1.py", line 38, in setOIDVal                                              
    oid, val = oidVal[0], oidVal[1]                                                                                                            
TypeError: 'Future' object does not support indexing
```

May be I am doing something stupid and I admit that I don't know much about SNMP, then, please, direct me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because CommandResponder <-> MIB controller interaction is [currently synchronous](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/entity/rfc3413/cmdrsp.py#L245). In other words, you can't `yield from` MIB controller, you can only `return` from it. And it can't be a `coroutine`. Once you remove these two things, your code might work alright.

It is definitely feasible to refactor pysnmp code in a way that `mgmtFun` (in the code I linked above) could return `Future` which fire the rest of the code (e.g. `sendVarBinds`) once `Future` is done. That would let you have your MIB controller asynchronous.

This this what you need? Then consider a PR or FR against pysnmp.